# Ruby: Difference between map and inject

Tags: ruby

Reading various explanations here on SO, they have been described as such:

**Map:**

> The map method takes an enumerable object and a block, and runs the block for each element

**Inject:**

> Inject takes a value and a block, and it runs that block once for each element of the list.

Hopefully you understand why I feel they seem pretty similar on the surface. When would I pick one over the other, and is there any clear-cut difference between them?

Comment: Have you tried reading the official documentation for [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [`inject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)?

Comment: I think the downvotes are unwarranted. SO is more than happy to repeat even the most basic of core language documentation if it hasn't been asked about before on SO. Often, the various answers use different wording to explain the same thing even if they don't add anything new in terms of ideas. Sometimes that's a big help to get the concept down intuitively.

Also, I've been surprised by unexpected subtleties brought up in the answers in SO on matters I thought were simple and boring.

So yeah, RTFM, but then come to SO and ask away if it hasn't been asked before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It helps if you consider that `inject` is also aliased as `reduce`. `map` is used to transform a list, e.g. convert all strings in the array to uppercase, whereas `inject` takes an argument (usually an accumulator) and modifies that.

Examples:

```
 %w(a b c).map(&:upcase) #=> ["A", "B", "C"]
 [*1..4].inject(:+) #=> 10
```

If you want to read more, what `inject` does is referred to as a [fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29).

Comment: The way you put it made it easier to understand the concepts. Thanks!

Comment: For something that is essentially an aggregate function, I find it much more readable and intuitive to do `(1..4).sum #=> 10`

Comment: @nroose This question wasn't tagged Rails. `(1..4).sum #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `sum' for 1..4:Range` in plain Ruby.

Answer (score 4):

[`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) takes an object as its argument, and did some operations and return back that modified object.

```
arr = []
[1,2].inject(arr) { |s,e| s << e }
arr # => [1,2]
```

In the above example, see I passed an empty array `arr`, but after calling `#inject`, inside the block I did `concatenation` operation and to that `arr`. After that I printed it, and I can see `arr` now holds the entries, which are `1,2`.

[`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) creates a new `Enumerable` object, which is created based on the receiver `Enumerable` object, on which you called it. It will take each element from the reciever, and will do some operation and will put into the new Enumerable element, then next and next and so on..

```
arr = [1,2]
arr.map { |e| e + 1 } # => [2,3]
arr # => [1,2]
```

With `#map`, block is taking each argument and incrementing it by `1`, and the incremented value it is putting the same index in the new array from which index it took the original element. But the final array is a new array, which has no connection with `arr`. When I did `p arr`, I got the same contents in `arr` which it had before starting the `#map` operations.

Answer (score 3):

With `inject` you're usually returning one value (usually used for math), while with map you're returning an array.

Comment: ...though one often sees `a.inject([])` and `({})`,

Comment: I find inject so confusing and map so much more intuitive. And if you are just summing something then use each or an aggregate function on the array you end up with.